# rxjs 5 publishReplay refCount

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I can't figure out how `publishReplay().refCount()` works.

For example (https://jsfiddle.net/7o3a45L1/):

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(observer =>  {
  console.log("call"); 
  // expensive http request
  observer.next(5);
}).publishReplay().refCount();

subscription1 = source.subscribe({next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)});
subscription1.unsubscribe();
console.log(""); 

subscription2 = source.subscribe({next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)});
subscription2.unsubscribe();
console.log(""); 

subscription3 = source.subscribe({next: (v) => console.log('observerC: ' + v)});
subscription3.unsubscribe();
console.log(""); 

subscription4 = source.subscribe({next: (v) => console.log('observerD: ' + v)});
subscription4.unsubscribe();
```

gives the following result:

> call observerA: 5
>
> observerB: 5 call observerB: 5
>
> observerC: 5 observerC: 5 call observerC: 5
>
> observerD: 5 observerD: 5 observerD: 5 call observerD: 5

1) Why are observerB, C and D called multiple times?

2) Why "call" is printed on each line and not in the beginning of the line?

Also, if i call `publishReplay(1).refCount()`, it calls observerB, C and D 2 times each.

What i expect is that every new observer receives the value 5 exactly once and "call" is printed only once.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`publishReplay(x).refCount()` combined does the following:

- It create a `ReplaySubject` which replay up to *x* emissions. If *x* is not defined then it replays the complete stream.
- It makes this `ReplaySubject` multicast compatible using a refCount() operator. This results in *concurrent* subscriptions receiving the same emissions.

Your example contains a few issues clouding how it all works together. See the following revised snippet:

```js
var state = 5
var realSource = Rx.Observable.create(observer =>  {
  console.log("creating expensive HTTP-based emission"); 
  observer.next(state++);
//  observer.complete();
  
  return () => {
    console.log('unsubscribing from source')
  }
});


var source = Rx.Observable.of('')
  .do(() => console.log('stream subscribed'))
  .ignoreElements()
  .concat(realSource)
.do(null, null, () => console.log('stream completed'))
.publishReplay()
.refCount()
;
    
subscription1 = source.subscribe({next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)});
subscription1.unsubscribe();
 
subscription2 = source.subscribe(v => console.log('observerB: ' + v));
subscription2.unsubscribe();
    
subscription3 = source.subscribe(v => console.log('observerC: ' + v));
subscription3.unsubscribe();
    
subscription4 = source.subscribe(v => console.log('observerD: ' + v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

When running this snippet we can see clearly that it is not emitting duplicate values for *Observer D*, it is in fact creating new emissions for every subscription. How come?

Every subscription is unsubscribed before the next subscription takes place. This effectively makes the refCount decrease back to zero, no multicasting is being done.

The issue resides in the fact that the `realSource` stream does not complete. Because we are not multicasting the next subscriber gets a fresh instance of `realSource` through the ReplaySubject and the new emissions are prepended with the previous already emitted emissions.

So to fix your stream from invoking the expensive HTTP request multiple times you have to complete the stream so the publishReplay knows it does not need to re-subscribe.

Answer (score 10):

Generally: The `refCount` means, that the stream is hot/shared as long as there is at least 1 subscriber - however, it is being reset/cold when there are no subscribers.

This means if you want to be absolutely sure that nothing is executed more than once, you should not use `refCount()` but simply `connect` the stream to set it hot.

As an additional note: If you add an `observer.complete()` after the `observer.next(5);` you will also get the result you expected.

---

Sidenote: Do you really need to create your own custom `Obervable` here? In 95% of the cases the existing operators are sufficient for the given usecase.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you're using `publishReplay()`. It internally creates an instance of `ReplaySubject` that stores all values that go through.

Since you're using `Observable.create` where you emit a single value then every time you call `source.subscribe(...)` you append one value to the buffer in `ReplaySubject`.

You're not getting `call` printed at the beginning of each line because it's the `ReplaySubject` who emits its buffer first when you subscribe and then it subscribes itself to its source:

For implementation details see:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/multicast.ts#L63
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/ReplaySubject.ts#L54

The same applies when using `publishReplay(1)`. First it emits the buffered item from `ReplaySubject` and then yet another item from `observer.next(5);`

Comment: The only relating answer