# Caching And Refreshing of Data in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular-forms, angular-cache

I have this problem in my angular app that since I'm caching data. After I'm adding something using the onCreate() function. I called the getAll() function in the successfull subscribe function in order to get the new data. However, I still don't get the new data. I believe that it is because of the cache data in my service. How would i know if there's a new data or How would i fix my cache my existing datas and refreshing of data when there's new data?

> service

```
getAll() {
    if(!this.materials) {
        this.materials = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url)
                            .map((response => response))   
                            .publishReplay(1)
                            .refCount();

    }
    return this.materials;
  }
```

> getAll() ts

```
getAllMaterials() {
    this.subscription = this.materialsService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.materials = data.materials;
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
           alert("Error");
           console.log(error);
          });
  }
```

> onCreate() -ts

```
 onCreateMaterial(form: NgForm){

    const formData = {
      sku: form.value.sku,
      name: form.value.name,
      supplier_id: form.value.supplier,
      price: form.value.price
    }

    this.materialsService.addMaterial(formData)
      .subscribe(
          data => {
            let message = data.message;
            alert(message);
            console.log(data);
            this.modalRef.close();
            this.getAllMaterials();
          },
          error => {
             alert("Error Adding");
             console.log(error);
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some research on `.publishReplay().refCount()` [you can read it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189801/rxjs-5-publishreplay-refcount) I think the problem is that you are using `.publishReplay().refCount()` before you subscribe, so that the subject is marked as completed after one iteration, so it will never fire again. [Read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786396/rx-subject-loses-events/41789882) I am not familiar with this myself, but worth a shot.

If it's not that try to remove the parameter of publishReplay and try to manually unsubscribe to see if it has any results.