# ReplySubject turns whole combineLastest hot

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Live: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6aikyy?file=index.ts

```ts
const sub = new ReplaySubject(1);
const source = combineLatest(
  of('World'),
  sub,
).pipe(
  map(([, n]) => n) ,
  tap(x => console.log('Tap', x)),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
);

sub.next(1);

const subscription = source.subscribe(x => console.log('Sub', x));
sub.next(2);

subscription.unsubscribe();
sub.next(3);

console.log('pause');
sub.next(4);

source.subscribe(x => console.log('Sub', x));


/**
 * Tap 1 (unwanted)
 * Sub 1 (unwanted)
 * Tap 2
 * Sub 2
 * pause
 * Sub 2 (why exaclty does this happened?)
 * Tap 4
 * Sub 4
 */
```

This is simplified a bit, but it shows my problem well. In my actual code, I combine 1 `BehaviourSubject` and 2 `ReplySubject`s, then pipe it into `switchMap` and fetching data from the server. I really don't want to keep making HTTP calls unless someone actually listens.

Does someone know why do I get the first notification from the ReplaySubject (Tap 1 & Sub 1), and also why does "Sub 2" appear after the pause?

---

#### Actual test case

```ts
this.currentPage = new BehaviourSubject(1);
// Internal
const folderIDAndPage: Observable<[string, number]> = combineLatest(
  /** Angular's BehaviourSubject of URL maped to id */
  activatedRoute.url.pipe(
    switchMap(segments => folderService.getFoldersFromSegments(segments)),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  ),
  /** BehaviourSubject/ReplaySubject (either) of QueryString maped to page */
  this.currentPage.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  ),
).pipe(
  // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
);

// Public
this.folders = folderIDAndPage.pipe(
  switchMap(([folderID, page]) => folderService.getFfolders(folderID, page)),
  // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
);

// Public
this.files = folderIDAndPage.pipe(
  switchMap(([folderID, page]) => fileService.getFiles(folderID, page)),
  // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
);
```

As of now, I have it that if I don't subscribe to either, no HTTP will be made, but if I subscribe to files or folders, the `folderService.getFoldersFromSegments` seems to get called twice.

Comment: Why do use a `ReplaySubject` and not a `Subject`? If you don't want to make HTTP calls unless someone listens then I would suppose that you also don't want `Tap 3` and `Sub 3` logged, because there's no subscriber when you call `sub.next(3)`. The reason `Tap 1` and `Sub 1` are logged is the same as for `Tap 3` and `Sub 3`, i.e. your `ReplaySubject`. `Sub 2` is logged after `pause` because it's replayed by `publishReplay(1)` to a new subscriber. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42189801/9423231

Comment: I do need to be able to restore UI and for that I need it to be either behaviour or reply subject. And I do want `Sub 3` & `Tap 3` to happen, but I want it after the `pause`, once someone subscribes again

Comment: @fridoo I have slightly edited my question. I don't need the 3 anymore (will get skipped entirely) but want the 4th, but only once someone subscribes to it.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question regarding your actual problem (how to prevent multiple http calls in your scenario). You should then also describe in what case you want to prevent http calls, i.e. how do you use your `currentPage` BehaviorSubject? When does it emit new values? Where do you subscribe? How do you navigate around your app and when exaclty should a http call be made and when exactly not?

Comment: @fridoo There it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564281/rxjs-angular-prevent-multiple-http-on-multiple-subscribers