# RXJS/Angular Prevent multiple HTTP on multiple subscribers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have "mainData" service, it consists of 3 parts:

- `currentPage` used by paginator component to switch page. Can be updated at any point.
- `folders` contains all folders in the current folder. There are **2** components that use this observable (Types of listing of folder content)
- `files` contains all files in the current folder. There are **3** components that use this observable (Types of listing of folder content)

The default view is the one without folders, thus I would like not to make unnecessary HTTP calls.

```ts
public currentPage = new ReplaySubject(1);
public folders: Observable<FLFolder[]>;
public files: Observable<FLFile[]>;

constructor(
  activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  folderService: FolderService,
  fileService: FileService,
) {
  // Populate `this.currentPage`
  activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
    take(1),
    //  Wait until end of this sync tick. If no emission is made, it will use default in the next tick.
    takeUntil(timer(1, queueScheduler)),
    defaultIfEmpty<Params>({}),
  ).subscribe(query => {
    if (query.page) {
      this.currentPage = +query.page;
    } else {
      this.currentPage = 1;
    }
  });

  /** This observable is internal, only to be used by `folders` and `files` */
  const folderIDAndPage: Observable<[string, number]> = combineLatest(
    activatedRoute.url.pipe(
      switchMap(segments => folderService.getFoldersFromSegments(segments)),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ),
    this.currentPage.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ),
  ).pipe(
    // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount(),
  );

  this.folders = folderIDAndPage.pipe(
    switchMap(([folderID, page]) => folderService.getFfolders(folderID, page)),
    // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount(),
  );

  this.files = folderIDAndPage.pipe(
    switchMap(([folderID, page]) => fileService.getFiles(folderID, page)),
    // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount(),
  );
}
```

When there is no subscribe to either `folders`, or `files`, no HTTP are made. But even if one subscribes to only one of them, both `folders` and `files` get populated (while making the HTTP call) and updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`this.folders` and `this.files` are not being called here in this service. What's going on with the components?

Perhaps a refactor is in order? Forgive me if I'm off.

I setup my services with getters:

```
private _currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);
```

Then you can only get it from a component by accessing the getter:

```
public getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this._currentUser.asObservable();
}
```

This way it's more clear to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make the following change in your code and try -

```
const getFoldersFromSegments$ = activatedRoute.url.pipe(
  switchMap(segments => folderService.getFoldersFromSegments(segments)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
);

/** This observable is internal, only to be used by `folders` and `files` */
const folderIDAndPage: Observable<[string, number]> = combineLatest(
  getFoldersFromSegments$,
  this.currentPage.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  ),
).pipe(
  // Prevent repeating HTTP somehow...
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
);
```

BTW - You have used `take(1)` on `activatedRoute.queryParams` observable; It will make your `this.currentPage` to be changed only once. But you said,

> Can be updated at any point

, so is it not a contradiction? Or it is intentional?

Comment: It is intentional, as any next update to `currentPage` happens via `Subject.next` method, inside the paginator component. Also, could you explain what changed? I don't see why moving `publishReply` & `refCount` against the stream would help the situation.

Comment: @Akxe basically you want to share the result of the API whenever combinedLatest is subscribed. Now combinedLatest evaluates it’s all observables whenever any one of the observables emits the new value. By applying the publishreplay/refcount on api observable I think the same subscription will be used among all combinedLatest observable. This is my theory. As I could not setup my code like your scenarios so am not sure if it will work. I would appreciate if you could tell if this solution worked for you.